# irb extract Strings from within array

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I am working in a box from Nitro.io, so my environment is built with the last features.

Starts irb...

```
>name = "James", lname = "Smith"   
=> ["James", "Smith"]
```

It creates an array with these two strings. I could access them by `name[0]` or `name[1]` to get the **the output I need**:

```
>"First name " + name[0] + ", Last name " + name[1]   
=>"First name James, Last name Smith"
```

I need to get the same output by accessing the names that have the strings into the array.
Example:

```
>lname
=>"Smith"
```

But, how can I access to the **first name** ("James") as the same way as `lname` gets "Smith"? Something like:

```
>"First name " + ???? + ", Last name " + lname   
=>"First name James, Last name Smith"
```

This sentence is given to me to be evaluated by a script:

```
>name = "James", lname = "Smith"
```

I must get:

```
=>"First name James, Last name Smith"
```

I cannot change anything. I only can make the input in one line to be evaluated.
I have unsuccessfully tried (all gets the correct output, but the script do not accept them):

```
>"First name #{name[0]}, Last name #{name[1]}"    
>"First name " + name[0] + ", Last name " + name[1]     
>"First name " + name.first + ", Last name " + name.last    
>"First name " + name[0] + ", Last name " + lname
```

I think that the best approach is the last one of these four, but changing `name[0]` for the same kind of accessing like `lame`.

Comment: Try `name, lname = "James", "Smith"`. It will be more efficient as you will not need to get values by indices like `name[0]`. You will be able to get both values using direct variables

Comment: Thak all for your quick attention. I can not change the first input creating the array.

Comment: Great! if your problem has been solved, close the question by marking the answer as accepted...

Comment: > I can not change the first input creating the array....... didnt get u!

Comment: My script does't work with "First name #{name[0]}, Last name #{name[1]}" . I already need more solutions. **Thanks again for RAJ, Eli Rose, Mark Thomas and IS04**

Comment: Had your array been 'name = [last, first]', `name.first => last`, `name.last => first` might have been a bit confusing.

Comment: From the arbitrary requirements you are placing on the way things work, my guess is that this is for some sort of homework or assignment. If you want help, you need to explain all of the restrictions. name.first and name[0] should work fine in your string.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Rails, so please remove that tag. A Rails tag is a time-waster for those who only want to see Rails questions and would likely prevent those who filter out Rails questions from seeing the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Consider SO as a place to ask a question, not to have a conversation. When asking, keep it straight and to the point; Fluff will get edited out eventually. It's OK to edit your question and add/remove as necessary to clarify the question without providing a running commentary on the changes. If we need to see something from a previous edit we can; We can see all once we get enough points here. Finally, we don't care if you're new or experienced, a good question is a good question, and you'll get votes for asking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
name = "James", lname = "Smith"
```

This evaluates in a bit of an unexpected way:

```
name = ["James", (lname = "Smith")]
```

So, `name` is assigned an array of `"James"` and `lname = "Smith"` (which evaluates to `"Smith"`).

So, you've added 2 values to a context:

```
name = ["James", "Smith"]
lname = "Smith"
```

**You have no options** of accessing the first name but `name`'s methods as an `Array`.
`name[0]` and `name.first`, that's all.

Comment: Thanks D-side. You had answer completely my question, and now I understand what's going wrong with the validation by script. I have tried to vote your answer, but I already haven't reputation enough.

Comment: **I must mix both `name[0]` and `name.last`**. I think the script try the user make all possible combinations untill find the correct sentence....(weird)

Comment: @albergurpe I still don't get what exactly you're trying to achieve, I just clarified what's happening. And this code is **weird**. I mean, impractically weird. Where did you get it and how come you can't change it?

Comment: Thanks D-side for your help. I take your *answer as the correct one* because my script intends me to realize that I cannot access to the first element of the array the same way I do to the second one. *Only* one of the several possible combinations of the answers given by all of you **was accepted by my validation script** (I thought it was *weird* in that moment), but *only you* gave me the *key* to understand it (and what script tried to teach me). Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is create two variables, this stuff with commas is more complicated than you need.

```
irb(main):001:0> first_name = "James"
=> "James"
irb(main):002:0> last_name = "Smith"
=> "Smith"
irb(main):003:0> "First name " + first_name + ", Last name " + last_name
=> "First name James, Last name Smith"
irb(main):004:0>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using following syntax for multiple variable assignment.

```
name, lname = "James", "Smith"
```

It will be more efficient as you will not need to get values by indices like `name[0]`. You will be able to get both values using direct variables

**OR**

You can write it as:

```
name = "James"; lname = "Smith"
```

Mind that I am using semicolon, instead of comma. semi-colon is statement terminator in ruby.

Now you can use these variables like:

```
> "First name " + name + ", Last name " + lname
=>"First name James, Last name Smith"
```

Comment: Thanks RAJ, as I've rigth now commented above, I cannot change the declaration creating the array, and I'm being evaluated by a script. None of these answers works. Thanks again.

Comment: @albergurpe `name = "James", lname = "Smith"; fname = name[0]` and then you can access `fname`

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the `Array` methods `.first` and `.last`:

```
name = "James", "Smith"
#=> ["James", "Smith"]

name.first
#=> James

name.last
#=> Smith
```

Comment: Yes, this answer gets the correct output, but I am being evaluated by a script, and it doesn't work OK. Thanks, Mark. I need other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Given you can not change the starting input....

```
irb(main):001:0> name = "James", lname = "Smith"
=> ["James", "Smith"]
irb(main):002:0> fname = name.first
=> "James"
irb(main):003:0> "First name " + fname + ", Last name " + lname
=> "First name James, Last name Smith"
```

You can also use:

```
irb(main):004:0> name.first
=> "James"
irb(main):005:0> name.last
=> "Smith"
```

Comment: Thank you, Jeff, I cannot change the declaration of the array, neither modify it. My script will expect one line. and doesn't work 1>"First name " + name.first + ", Last name " + name.last" 2>"First name #{name[0]}, Last name #{name[1]}"